# Изменить значение кастомного атрибута

Tags: c#, рефлексия

Есть кастомный атрибут:

```
public class EnumFieldTextAttribute : Attribute
{
    // Methods
    public EnumFieldTextAttribute(string enumFieldText)
    {
        EnumFieldText = enumFieldText;
    }

    // Properties
    public string EnumFieldText { get; set; }
}
```

и enum, к которому он применяется:

```
{
    [EnumFieldText("Value 1")]
    ToBalance = 0,
    [EnumFieldText("Value 2")]
    ToBankAccount = 1
}
```

Возможно ли в рантайме изменить значение этого атрибута? Через рефлексию докопался только до конструктора, в который передаётся строковое значение. Как такого значения будто и нет

Comment: `Через рефлексию докопался` код вы конечно же не покажете?

Comment: enum не имеет инстанса на рантайме. enum это тип, и лежащие в нём поля константны, их менять, и менять что то о них не получится. Лучше использовать класс с статическими полями, если вам очень надо что то о них менять

Comment: @ZecosMAX, я прекрасно понимаю, что enum в итоге - константы. Но речь немного о другом. Если указывается значение для ``EnumFieldText``, то не уже ли нельзя докопаться до этого через рефлексию? =)